# MLFlow not configured, set environment variables

Tags: python, r, mlflow

Step 1: Installed anaconda ( also installed R and python in it) on AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu

Step 2:  Used “conda install -c conda-forge mlflow” command to install mlflow in conda(which is assumed to be used for both R and python)

Step 3: library(mlflow) command to use mlflow in R and import mlflow in python as per the MLFlow documentation but still unable to run the MLFlow as it gives the below error for R & Python

[image: Error Code in Jupyter Notebook for R]
[image: R Error Code]
[image: Python Notebook error code 1]
[image: Python Notebook error code 2]

Step 4: Used wine example that’s available in R & Python repository to validate MLFlow logging which is not happening. The MLFlow server is up and running

Comment: The docs suggest using `pip install mlflow` instead of conda.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, tried PIP and conda both.